# SqlFunctions.StringConvert doesn't work with doubles

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, sql-function

I have something like that in code

```
SqlFunctions.StringConvert( (double?) x.Latitude)
```

but it returns an integer always although it has a latitude value.

any help?

Comment: What is your `Latitude` value, it should return a string, not in `int`

Comment: @Habib It's value like that 30.084524379285227 but it always return 30

Comment: That is strange, could you check the query generated against your LINQ query through SQL Profiler

Comment: Have you tried the overloads for the `StringConvert` method?  Try `SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double?) x.Latitude, 10, 10);`

Comment: When I execute it on SQL server it returns the correct values of longitude and latitude 
but when I give it value like that 
SqlFunctions.StringConvert( (double?) x.Latitude,10,10)
it returns the right value but It has to be static based on the length of the double

Comment: @EvanL It works but It should be dynamic not static, any suggestions?

Comment: I submitted an answer that should give you the dynamic solution using the `StringConvert` method.

Comment: Can you post the complete Linq query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SqlFunctions.StringConvert(double?)` returns an integer converted to string.  To return a decimal value, you need to provide the other overload `SqlFunctions.StringConvert(double? vaue, int length, int decimals)` as follows:

```
SqlFunctions.StringConvert( (double?) x.Latitude, 20, 5)

// If x.Latitude = 34.75, then the result will be "34.75000"
```

From the STR documentation:

> The **number is rounded to an integer by default** or if the decimal
>   parameter is 0.

References:
[SqlFunctions.StringConvert Method (Nullable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487127%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[SqlFunctions.StringConvert Method (Nullable, Nullable, Nullable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466301%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[STR (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx)

Comment: If i did that it adds zeros on the right and I don't want this to happen

Comment: A possible alternative is to simply use `.ToList()` at the end of your Linq query, and then do the formatting using Linq to Objects with `x.Latitude.ToString()`.

Comment: @wdosanjos Linq doesn't support the function .ToString()

Comment: Linq-to-Entities (EF) does not support it, but Linq-to-Objects does.  So I'm suggesting using a "greedy" method like `.ToList()` to hydrate all the object only then use `x.Latitude.ToString()`.  If you provide your complete Linq query I can show you how.

Comment: what if i dont want rounding to happen for e.g if i just want function to return  '34' if input is '34.75'