# Alternate of Sql Functions in .net core 2.2

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am tying to convert my .net framework 4.6.1 project to .net core 2.2. I have got an error "The name Sql Functions does not exists in current context".I have been searching and haven't got any answer yet.

I have tried EF class functions but this didn't solve my problem

```
select new ReleaseBuildDashboardDto
                    {
                        // to fix
                        DateString = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)
                            SqlFunctions.DatePart("m", g.Key.Value)).Trim() +"/" +
                            SqlFunctions.DateName("dd", g.Key.Value) + "/" +
                            SqlFunctions.DateName("yyyy", g.Key.Value),
                        ScheduledCount = g.Count()
                    }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: What is the code trying to **do**? I'd strongly suggest returning dates from the database **as dates**.

Comment: @mjwills I am just tying to use built in sql functions

Comment: @mjwills is correct; however, installing the relevant NuGet package probably does what you want (or at least what you've asked for): https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you need to set reference to the System.Data.Object.

OR

try adding System.Data.Entity.SqlServer namespace and see if that works better.

Comment: may you are looking for this ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21732569/sqlfunctions-stringconvert-doesnt-work-with-doubles